# ERROR: syntax error at or near "group" LINE 4: ...E ST_DWithin

Tags: postgis, postgresql, plsql

I'm writing an SQL query but I am getting a syntax error on the line with the `GROUP BY`. What can possibly be the problem?

```
UPDATE intersection_points i
  SET nbr_victimes =  sum(tue+bl+bg)
    FROM accident_ma a
    WHERE ST_DWithin(i.st_intersection,a.geom_acc, 10000) group by i.st_intersection
```

Comment: Don't [cross-post questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36180128/327026)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have a group by in an update statement. See this stack overflow question: [GROUP BY in UPDATE FROM clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272412/group-by-in-update-from-clause)

You'll need to use a subquery, like:

```
UPDATE table t1 SET column1=sq.column1
FROM  (
   SELECT t2.column1, column2
   FROM   table t2
   JOIN   table t3 USING (column2)
   GROUP  BY column2
   ) AS sq
WHERE  t1.column2=sq.column2;
```

Comment: You should update your question, as suggested in your question on SO (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36180128/error-syntax-error-at-or-near-group):  "However, the use of ST_DWithin() in this query may complicate that quite a bit. Without much deeper knowledge of the table structures, relationships, and overall intent of this update there probably isn't much more help I can give. Essentially you're going to need to clarify for the database exactly what records need to be updated and how to update them, which may involve changing your query to this latter sub-select syntax in some way."